# Creating Range Table

Tags: c#

First the thread name might be a little strange but i will try my best to explain what i want to do here so you can suggest me a good thread name.

I want to create a function to return the employee level by checking his experience

If experience is 0~50 he is level 1
If experience is 50~150 he is level 2
... and so on till level 100

What i am thinking of is creating a const int that holds all required exp for each level

```
public const int Level1 = 50,
                 Level2 = 150...;
```

so is there a way to make a function to return what i want ? without the use of 1000++ lines ?!.

Please don't consider my question as a spam i am only very confused and i will try my best to clarify my idea if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int level = Math.Min(10, experience / 10);
```

Would that do?

If you want to have 0-10 -> 1 and 11-20 -> 2 etc, change it like this:

```
int level = Math.Min(10, (experience + 9) / 10);
```

If there is no pattern at all in experience gains, or some very obscure one, you could use this:

```
var level = 1;

var levelRequirements = new int[] {10, 20, 50, 150, 300};
for (int i = 0; i < levelRequirements.Length; i++)
{
    if (levelRequirements[i] > currentExperience)
        break;
    level++;
}
```

And now for my final update:

```
var level = 0;

var levelRequirement = 0;
var levelRequirementAddition = 50;

while (currentExperience >= levelRequirement)
{
    levelRequirement += levelRequirementAddition;
    levelRequirementAddition += 50;
    level++;
}
```

Comment: but what if Level 1 requires 50, Level 2 requires 150 Level 3 requires 300 Level 4 requires 500. i think it is not a constant value

Comment: @RuneS than you have to do a separate case for each of them, involving multiple lines of code.  you can use different design patterns to move the lines of code around, but they'll have to be there

Comment: @RuneS is there some sort of mathematical function in the size this experience requirement goes up? Doubles every time, or 50 more each time, or...?

Comment: @RuneS  If you know the pattern than you can solve it with some arithmetic.  we're not going to be able to do a "catches all cases" algorithm for you.

Comment: no i don't want you to do it for me i just want you to tell me the most elegant way to do it given the pattern above so i don't have to involve thousands of if,else functions

Comment: @RuneS use a mathematic formula

Comment: @RenéWolferink finally this is going to be logarithmic as in any RPG xp formula

Comment: @honag. yea you just hit the point like in MMORPG Experience Formula what is the best way to determine the character level depending on his experience

Comment: it's not logarithmic, but exponential, there is a difference

Comment: The function that gives the level given the experience will be logarithmic. The inverse function that gives the experience given the level will be exponential ... this is the same

Comment: @RunesS if you want this serie  50,150,300,500,750,1050,1400,1800,2250,2750,3300,3900,4550,5520 to match the level f(level) = 25 * (level * level + level).

Comment: see my answer below for a more straightforward computation

Answer (score 1):

Since the formula for the xp required for the level `x` seems to be `25*(x²+x)`

You can use the inverse function :

```
public int GetLevel(int xp)
{
    return (int)(Math.Sqrt(1 + 4 * xp / 25) - 1) / 2;
}
```

Comment: To me this seems like a request for a very linear levelling with a ceiling rather than a logarithmic value.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int ReturLevel(int experience)
{
    return (experience-1)/10 + 1;
}
```

you may remove the `-1` in `(experience-1)` if you meant "If experience is 1~9"

leave it if you meant "If experience is 11~20 he is level 2"

Edit:

IF your experience to level function doesn't follow any pattern, than Yes, you'll have to make a separate case for each one of them.

```
if(experience > 20)
    return level 3;
else if(experience > 10)
    return level 2;
else
    return level 1;
```

different design patterns can affect how and were you add these different cases, but they'll have to be added if you have no pattern.

Comment: you can see the experience here : 50,150,300,500,750,1050,1400,1800,2250,2750,3300,3900,4550,5520... I think it follows no pattern ? isn't it ?